# Complex fill in the blanks query in MS Access 2010

Tags: ms-access

I have looked and haven't found a method on here to do this.  I am assuming my search is skewed and I just missed it, if this is the case, please let me know.

Anywhooo, I have a large and unwieldy report coming out of SAP every day.  Because it will often have some strangeness, we import that into an Access database so we can keep an eye on the stuff we need in our department.  I am using a combination of 6 fields to create a primary key in Access.  The information in those fields is about the only thing consistent I get out of this SAP report, but the remainder of the data can be considered dynamic and can change from day to day.  Usually this is a matter of filling in a few blanks, Occasionally this is changing existing data, and on rare occasions, it may involve deleting data out of a handful of fields.

The SAP report is around 130 columns of data, So I'm looking for an efficient way to roll in the changes without overwriting what folks put in there manually.

EDIT:
Here is the way this is used.  SAP (for reasons I'm not going to go into) sometimes will have bad data show up in the daily report.  We are using Access to track and put the correct data in to something that we can generate much more accurate summaries.  What the users put in is to be considered true and accurate.

The transactions we are tracking can take a long time to complete.  Most take around 30 days to complete.  That's why I will have blank fields on one day, and several of them to be filled in on the next.  We might not get any for the next few days and then a bunch more are filled in later.  That is the normal flow.

What I have to account for is the odd occasion where a mistake is made early in the process.  At a certain point, an error will break SAP's ability to update anything at all in the report we have to use.

I have 3 fields set up that trigger what my users daily work is going to be.  There is a logical flow so that user 1 completes what he needs to do and then that record will show up on User 2's report.  These fields will also stop the general update process in an exception report if there is a difference in what is coming in from SAP, and what is already in my database.

What I am looking for is some way to systematically fill in blank fields, on existing records in access.  I do not want to overwrite if something is in a field, only the null values.  I can do this on one field at a time, but each record has about 130 fields.  I'm wondering if there is a way I could do this in just 1 query?

Thanks all!  I hope the edit makes more sense now

Comment: If you feel you must delete data, you must be able to identify these and separate them from date newly entered by other users. It's an conceptual question not about coding.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, but it sounds like you want a conditional Update query.  Sometimes it will fill in data in specific fields, sometimes it will change data in specific fields and sometimes it will delete data in specific fields.  So, it kind of depends on the best way to determine which is the correct case.  Then, either build that into your query or write VBA that will create and run the proper query.  Without more specific information, that's the best I can offer.

Comment: @JohnnyBones thanks.  I re-read my question and it's not really clear.  I'll edit.  been a really busy day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple google for "Access SQL update null values" could have yeilded you what you need. But if all you need to do is fill constant values into empty fields then something like:

```
UPDATE Table SET Table.field1 = VALUE
WHERE Table.field2 is NULL;
```

Now if this data is different for each record based on; say data from another field, then you may need to write some VBA to build that value/string for you. But otherwise if you are JUST updating null fields to include data, then a simple UPDATE statement will do

EDIT Based on new info:

So if I'm understanding correctly: you have two tables. One table with the blank fields and another table that contains the values you need.

If this is the case, you can use a similar UPDATE statement, but use an inner join to get the data you need from table B to fill in table A

```
UPDATE TableA INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.KeyField = TableB.KeyField 
SET TableA.NullField = TableB.NotNullField
WHERE TableA.NullField Is NULL;
```

Comment: That's what I was finding before I asked.  I use some of those kinds of update queries in other places.  I'm looking for something that will look at a field with a null value, compare it with a table that has the new incoming information, and then overwrite the null field while leaving the fields that have something alone

Comment: Thanks!  I'm not great with SQL, but If I am reading this right it compares Table A with Table B based on an inner join.  does the SET TableA.Nullfield = TableB.NotNullField account for all instances across all fields?  I'm willing to brute force this, but it would be tedious

Comment: You are correct. The inner join will include all records where the key fields match from each table.
Edit (Hit enter accidentally)
However, the SET statement will only set the Null field with the not null matching field. If you have multiple fields you can add more field updates to the single query:
`SET TableA.NullField = TableB.NotNullField, TableA.NullField2 = TableB.NotNullField2`
You can also look into using IIF statements in your query to go across all the fields you need

Comment: When possible, a single SQL statement is always nice and even within Access, SQL statements are often more efficient than writing VBA code.  However, if you don't want to manually write and maintain a single statement for 130+ fields, I suggest writing a VBA procedure that will enumerate the fields in your tables, looking for Nulls and updating appropriately.  OR, you could write similar code to generate your SQL statement for you... giving you the best of both worlds: If your fields ever change, then you can simply regenerate your SQL, but in the mean time you have a single statement.